# How does one derive with respect to a matrix when that matrix is part of a summation whose result is inverted?

Tags: matrix-calculus

A and B are matrices, a and b are scalars.

How would I derive the following expression with respect to A?

$$ \frac{\partial} {\partial A} ((a* A + b * B)^{-1})$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $C=(aA+bB)$ and $F=C^{-1}$. Note that $I=CC^{-1}=CF$.

Take the differential of that last expression and simplify it
$$\eqalign{
0 &= C\,dF+dC\,F \cr
C\,dF &= -dC\,F \cr
dF &= -F\,dC\,F \cr
}$$
Now express it in terms of $A$.
$$\eqalign{
dF &= -Fa\,dA\,F \cr
}$$
At this point, we're stuck because the derivative of a matrix wrt a matrix is a 4th order tensor.

One way to proceed is to vectorize the matrices by column stacking. 
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(dF)
 &= -{\rm vec}(Fa\,dA\,F) \cr
 &= -(F^T\otimes Fa)\,{\rm vec}(dA) \cr
\frac{\partial\,{\rm vec}(F)}{\partial\,{\rm vec}(A)}
 &= -F^T\otimes Fa \cr
}$$
where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.

Comment: I'm going to try your made up words when I wake up. Thanks for the answer :)